# Python version on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to "Training on the Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset on Google Cloud" https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md
And I'm reach to "Starting Training and Evaluation Jobs on Google Cloud ML Engine" step.

but I have problem, the Google Cloud SDK support python 2.7.X and tensorflow support python 3.5.x or python 3.6.x on windows.

My OS: Windows 10 64bit.
and I have both versions of python.

If I run this command:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training desktop_6bsr85u_hp_object_detection_13  
--runtime-version 1.2 --job-dir=gs://bucketname987/train --packages 
dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz --module-name 
object_detection.train --region us-central1 --config 
object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml -- --
train_dir=gs://bucketname987/train
--pipeline_config_path=gs://bucketname987/data
/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config
```

If I use python 3.5.x this error occur in cmd:

```
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: invalid token (files.py, line 90)
gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base
from googlecloudsdk.calliope import arg_parsers
from googlecloudsdk.core import log
from googlecloudsdk.core import properties
from googlecloudsdk.core import config
from googlecloudsdk.core.util import files as file_utils
def MakeDir(path, mode=0777):
SyntaxError: invalid token
This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems 
with your Python interpreter.
Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 
executable:
C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point 
to a working Python 2.7 executable.
If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using 
the instructions here:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
```

And If I use python 2.7.X this error occur in Google cloud Platform:

```
The replica ps 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 51, in <module> from object_detection.builders import model_builder File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 29, in <module> from object_detection.meta_architectures import ssd_meta_arch File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 31, in <module> from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 24, in <module> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot The replica ps 1 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 51, in <module> from object_detection.builders import model_builder File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 29, in <module> from object_detection.meta_architectures import ssd_meta_arch File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 31, in <module> from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 24, in <module> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot The replica ps 2 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 51, in <module> from object_detection.builders import model_builder File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 29, in <module> from object_detection.meta_architectures import ssd_meta_arch File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 31, in <module> from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 24, in <module> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

```
To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=85763115141&resource=ml_job%2Fjob_id%2Fdesktop_6bsr85u_hp_object_detection_12&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22ml_job%22%0Aresource.labels.job_id%3D%
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Solve what problem? Downloading an older version of Python? Or upgrading Google Cloud SDK?

Comment: I have both versions,  but its fail if I do this command:  gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_`date +%s` \
    --runtime-version 1.2 \
    --job-dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train \
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
    --module-name object_detection.train \
    --region us-central1 \
    --config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
    -- \
    --train_dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train \
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/data/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config

Comment: Please edit your question to include that and the error it generates

Comment: I think should use interepter but I don't know how.

Comment: No... That command is a bash command, not Python

Comment: All of those commands on the README are for Mac/Linux. You would need to replace all the variable substitutions for Windows equivalents, which has nothing to do with Python

Comment: I have modified the question.
If possible explain the answer to me, because I am a beginner.
and I don't know if there is diff between cmd and bash.

Answer (score 0):

> ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot

Looks like you need to install matplotlib

And the code isn't running in windows given that Python is being executed from `/root/.local/...`